# "/" Get Removed from the URL When onclick Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I change current `url` of the webpage using `window.history.replaceState()` without refreshing the page. so that I can append to current `url` YouTube `VideoID` when ever user clicks on the video which are listed on this page and plays the same video in the same page.

Let us assume sample `urls` are -

Default Video page
`http://www.domain.com/video/`
After User clicks on video URL changes to removing the last `/`

`http://www.domain.com/video#Se1y2R5QRKU`

I want url to remain with `/`
`http://www.domain.com/video/#wckLzQDTm6s`

Here is the script I am using but I am not sure what is remove last `/` from the `url`

```
var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
var match = URL.match(regExp);
if (match && match[7].length == 11) {
    //console.log(match[7]);
    currentURL = document.URL;
    // alert(currentURL.slice(0, currentURL.lastIndexOf('#')));
    console.log(currentURL.slice(0, currentURL.indexOf('#')));
    var sliceURL = currentURL.slice(0, currentURL.indexOf('#'));
    var newURL = sliceURL + '#' + match[7];
    window.history.replaceState(null, "Video Gallery", newURL);
    return match[7];
} else {
    //alert("Could not extract video ID.");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your currentURL initially does not contain the #, the indexOf will return -1 and the result is that the last character (your slash) will be removed. You should explicitly check whether the hash is inside the currentURL before slicing it:

```
var hashIndex = currentURL.indexOf('#');
var sliceURL = (hashIndex != -1) ? currentURL.slice(0, hashIndex) : currentURL;
```